# AutoMapper for Many-to-Many Relationship

Tags: c#, automapper

I am new to Automapper and I am trying to map a relationship for a many-to-many table configuration.

I have 3 tables:

AppUser -

```
public class AppUser
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<AppUserCompanySettings> AppUserCompanySettings { get; set; }  = new List<AppUserCompanySettings>();
}
```

CompanySettings -

```
public class CompanySettings
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string CompanyName { get; set; }
    public string CompanyRegistrationNumber { get; set; }
    public bool isActive { get; set; }
    public bool isArchived { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<AppUserCompanySettings> AppUserCompanySettings { get; set; } = new List<AppUserCompanySettings>();
}
```

AppUserCompanySettings -

```
public class AppUserCompanySettings
{
    public int AppUserId { get; set; }
    public virtual AppUser AppUser { get; set; }
    public int CompanySettingsId { get; set; }
    public virtual CompanySettings CompanySettings { get; set; }
}
```

I then created a CompanyDto

```
public class CompanyDto
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string CompanyName { get; set; }
    public string CompanyRegistrationNumber { get; set; }
    public bool isActive { get; set; }
    public bool isArchived { get; set; }
    public int UserId { get; set; }
}
```

And then an Automapper -

```
CreateMap<CompanySettings, CompanyDto>()
        .ForMember(dest => dest.UserId, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.AppUserCompanySettings.AppUserId));
```

I get the following error when compiling:

```
'ICollection<AppUserCompanySettings>' does not contain a definition for 'AppUserId' and no accessible extension method 'AppUserId' accepting a first argument of type 'ICollection<AppUserCompanySettings>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

Could somebody please tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: What are you trying to do with `src.AppUserCompanySettings.AppUserId`? The property `CompanySettings.AppUserCompanySettings` is a `ICollection<>` and does not have a `AppUserId` property. That is also explained in the error message you get. Do you want to use something like `First()` to access the first element from that collection?

Comment: As @Progman said, you should use `First()`, since you can't map collection property to a single `UserId`. On the other hand, i don't quite get why your `CompanyDto` has a single `UserId` property, since you have a many-to-many relationship? Shouldn't it be ICollection<int> Users? That would make more sense (only if it's not a requirement you have)

Comment: Recommend not calling classes plural names; call the class singular and any `List<SingularClassName>` has a plural name. Helps you remember  whether something is a 1 or a many end of a relationship.. If you had `class Addresses` then a `List<Addresses>` would end up being called `Addresseses` (?) which is really confusing. If a class represents a collection, call it `-Collection`, otherwise save plurality for properties that return collections

Comment: Hi guys.  Thanks for the response.  I want to be able to extract all companies that are linked to a specific UserId when I call the API get GetCompaniesByUserId.

Comment: I have changed all my Class names to singular now.

Comment: When I run my API at the moment for GetCompanies (so return all companies) I get the following output (I commented out the current Mapping and added ```CreateMap<CompanySetting, CompanyDto>();```

{
        "id": 1,
        "companyName": "My Test Company",
        "companyRegistrationNumber": "1991/123456/07",
        "isActive": true,
        "isArchived": false,
        "userId": 0
    },

I want to populate the userId linked to the company

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I think finally got it.  Thanks everyone.

Completed AutoMapper code:

```
CreateMap<CompanySetting, CompanyDto>()
                .ForMember(dest => dest.UserId, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.AppUserCompanySettings.Select(y => y.AppUserId).FirstOrDefault()));
```